# error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch) in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have created one project in Eclipse ,but now i am converting that project to android studio project. But When i am trying to run that converted project, I am getting "error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)" in Messeges tab of android studio

my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pcs.sliderringtineproj"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

}
}
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
dependencies {
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/fmmr.jar')
compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar')
compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.15.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the build.gradle file of your application module and add the following to the section called `android`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Comment: Sir, i have already tried that but it shows can not resolve symbol sourceCompatibility, also same warning for targetCompatibility

Comment: @SritamJagadev post the content of your build.gradle file.

Comment: And one more question: which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: i am using android studio version 1.0.1